# Updating User Profile in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I've been trying to update the avatar profile of a user, through image intervention, tho I cannot seem to update it. The $user->save isn't being read by Laravel

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request) {
        if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/images/avatars/' . $filename) );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->update();
        }
```

Comment: I've imported the following classes below,

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

I can add more details in order to help solve my problem

Comment: $user = Auth::user(); instead of this, try this: $user = User::findOrFail(auth()->id());

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Auth::user() is not your model. Please try:

```
$user = User::query()
    ->whereId(auth()->user()->id)
    ->update([
        'avatar' => $filename
    ]);
```